# How to extend the Spring Security's @Preauthorize with custom validating rule?

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Spring Security provides some convinent method-control annotations:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('ADD')")
```

I want to extend it with some custom method like

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasCompany('XX')")
```

and its validation data should come from a JWT token.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to do it, but what @Andrew mentioned would be easier. Just pointing out that you said you want to check if your JWT token has specific company "XX", then it will be

`@PreAuthorize("@yourBeanName.customMethod(authentication)")`

and inside of yourBeanName instance, you need to implement a method to extract company information from it and compare those two,

Or, probably you can do something like

`@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasCompany('XX')")`

same as what normal SpringEL can do with oauth2 access token.

To do that,

1. you need to implement your own DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler ( check OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler for comparison )
2. and when you implement createEvaluationContextInternal() method, you need new OAuth2 expression handler, not OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods since it doesn't have "hasCompany()" custom method. Just create a new class that extends OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods and add hasCompany() method, and plug it in your new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a method in custom bean implementation `@PreAuthorize("@yourBeanName.customMethod(authentication.principal.username)")`